# How to create a core dump even if the process is normally running?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, remote-debugging, coredump

Under Linux, when a process crashes, a core dump will be created.

However, I want to create a core dump when the process doesn't crash, but looks buggy. A remote expert need the core dump to analyze.

Under Windows, we can create a dump file of a process through task manager, and after that, the process is still running.

Is it possible under Linux?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Call `gdb`, then

```
attach pid
gcore
```

where `pid` is the process id of the process in question.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [gcore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) utility right from command line:

```
gcore [-o filename] pid
```

By the way, if you want to see only stack trace of the process, `gstack` utility will do the job.

Both utilities come with `gdb`.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it within your code with:

```
if (fork() == 0) abort();
```

Comment: This likely isn't the best solution but boy is it clever :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do this programmatically, try using [google-coredumper](https://code.google.com/p/google-coredumper/). Their example:

```
#include <google/coredumper.h>
...
WriteCoreDump('core.myprogram');
/* Keep going, we generated a core file,
 * but we didn't crash.
 */
```